# Куда делись маршруты по умолчанию в ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Куда делись маршруты по умолчанию в ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Разве в 3 еще были?

Comment: В третей версии есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App_Start/RouteConfig.cs